# What is this called by gathering the meaning from a sentence?

Tags: nlp

What would this process of gathering the meaning of a sentence be called? What would the segments derived from the sentence be called?

```
"John and Derrek both love cake"
    -> John loves cake
    -> Derrek loves cake

"John was mad that the weather was rainy today"
     -> John was mad
     -> weather was rainy today
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called **relation extraction**, it is a subdomain of Natural Language Processing. Often, you first have to apply **Named Entity recognition** or **Concept extraction** to extract the entity or concept. You can then extract the relations betweens the entities with several approaches.